# Passing a list of arguments to a function that includes keyword arguments

Tags: python, list, function, dictionary, arguments

I'd like to generate a large list of lists to pass to a function. Part of this is passing keyword arguments, but I can't seem to get it to work, as the keyword dict gets scooped up as a positional argument:

```
mylist = [
['cheese', 'toast', 'bread', {exempt=True}],
['bagel', 'apple', 'oatmeal', {exempt=True}],
]

for i in mylist:
    myfunc(*i)

def myfunc(first, *args, exempt=False, **kwargs):
   if exempt:
        return
```

Hopefully this gets the idea across. Is this sort of implementation possible?

Comment: you should use a sequence for positional arguments, e.g. `args = (1,2,3)`, and then a `dict` for keyword arguments, `kwargs = {"foo":42, "bar":"baz"}` then use `myfunc(*args, **kwargs)`. So maybe a list of args, kwargs pairs

Comment: The data needs to be structured in a way that makes it possible to tell, which are the positional and which are the keyword arguments. After all, a `dict` is a perfectly valid positional argument. That's a *design* question; once there is a concrete task, the remaining question is "how do I pass the dict as keyword arguments?", for which I have linked a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest having a list of args, kwargs pairs, like this:

```
mylist = [
    (['cheese', 'toast', 'bread'], {'exempt': True}),
    (['bagel', 'apple', 'oatmeal'], {'exempt': True}),
]

def myfunc(first, *args, exempt=False, **kwargs):
   if exempt:
        return

for args, kwargs in mylist:
    myfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

If you're stuck with `mylist` in its original format, you could do this to neatly assign the last element to `kwargs` and the remainder to `args`:

```
for *args, kwargs in mylist:
    myfunc(*args, **kwargs)
```

but you need to be very certain then that the last element is always the `kwargs` dict (or add code to check that it is and substitute an empty dict if it's not).